# How do I mock an Amazon SQS endpoint when testing a Camel application

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, apache-camel

I am writing a Spring Boot application that uses Camel to listen to an SQS queue. Route definition:

```
from("aws-sqs://my-s3-notification-queue" +
    "?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient" +
    "&deleteAfterRead=false")
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, S3EventNotification.class)
    .bean(s3NotificationHandler);
```

`sqsClient` is defined as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` file.

When running tests, I would like to mock the SQS endpoint so that I don't actually connect to AWS. How do I do this? I've tried writing my tests like

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

This should work if I'm reading the docs correctly, but it still tries to connect to AWS. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Localstack**](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)
using this you can mock multiple AWS service from your local system, without connecting AWS.

Comment: especially for unit tests, the container version works best.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much my answer would help you since I do not know of *apache camel*. I am mocking *HttpServletRequest* object and assume same concept can be use here.

So, in your test

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints
public class ApplicationTests {
    @Mock
    public MyRoute myRoute;

    @Before
    public void init() {  
       when(myRoute.configure()).thenReturn("what you are returning");
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

And your *myRoute* class would looks similar to,

```
class MyRoute{
  public void configure(){
    from("aws-sqs://my-s3-notification-queue" +
    "?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient" +
    "&deleteAfterRead=false")
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, S3EventNotification.class)
    .bean(s3NotificationHandler);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/aws-sqs.html
I'm also looking to solve the same problem, but my problem is more specific. I don't want to talk to aws while testing. As such I want to use localstack to mock the aws resources. But can't figure out a way to do that. The challenge that I'm facing at the moment is that, the camel routes are supposed to defined as: "aws-sqs:queuename.." but when I run localstack my queue endpoint is like: "http://localist:37010/queue/queuename".

Comment: I'm also having similar problem. Were you able to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Camel has a junit test suite that supporting mocking those endpoints. http://camel.apache.org/camel-test.html

We actually use Spock for unit testing and it was fairly easy to follow the same pattern.This is how the setup looks for us :

```
   DefaultCamelContext context
   MessagePipeline messagePipeline
   MockEndpoint resultEndpoint
   ProducerTemplate producerTemplate
   def setupMessagePipeLine() {
        context = new DefaultCamelContext()
        context.addRoutes(messagePipeline)
        context.start()
        producerTemplate = context.createProducerTemplate()
        resultEndpoint = MockEndpoint.resolve(context, 'mock:log:out')
    }
```

Here MessagePipelines is the class that extends RouteBuilder and the input path is 
`'direct:start'`, output is `'mock:log:out'`. Hopefully this helps.